# Does AngularJS component pattern bindings has specific naming format?

Tags: angularjs, binding

I am learning component pattern in angularJS. I am trying to use bindings in component pattern. The binding name I have used is **firstName** . But the problem is it is not binding. When I replaced **firstName** with anything else like **abc** it works fine. Can anyone say what may have caused that problem?

The component code is as follow:

```js
(function () {
        angular.module('mainModule').component('heroList', {
            template: '<p>Hello from component {{$ctrl.firstName}}</p>',
            //controller: 'HeroListController',
            bindings: {
                firstName: '='
            }
        })

    }());
```

The index.html and index.js that calls this component is:

```js
    (function () {
       var app= angular.module('mainModule', []);

       app.controller('myCtrl', function () {
           var vm = this;
           vm.firstName = "John";
           vm.lastName = "Doe";
       })
    
   
    }())
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular Components</title>
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <script src="heroes/hero-list.component.js"></script>
        <script src="heroes/hero-list.controller.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="mainModule" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">

    {{vm.firstName}}  {{vm.lastName}}

    <hero-list firstName="vm.firstName"><hero-list>

</body>
</html>
```

The output I get is:

```
> John Doe
>
>Hello from component
```

But after I replace **firstName** with **abc** I get the desired output.

```
>John Doe
>
>Hello from component John
```

Could anyone help me with what may have caused this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bindings use the same camelCase notation as Component Names e.g. they are separated using dashes.  So to use `firstName` binding, you use it as:

```
<hero-list first-name="vm.firstName"><hero-list>
```